# Is there a function in numpy where it will return a matrix of each row of vector raised from a power of 0 to integer

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a vertical vector X = [[1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.power.html),[2],[3]] and integer pow = 2.
Is there a function in numpy where it will return a matrix of each row of vector x raised from a power of 0 to pow (pow = 2)

The above example should return a matrix

```
[[1, 1, 1],
 [1, 2, 4],
 [1, 3, 9]]
```

I looked at [numpy.power](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.power.html), however returns an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking for is

[numpy.vander](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vander.html)

Answer (score 1):

Following the [`rules of broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), we could extend to 2D and then *raise to power* with a ranged array -

```
X[:,None]**np.arange(3)  # Or np.power(X[:,None], np.arange(3))
```

Sample run -

```
In [7]: X = np.array([1,2,3])

In [8]: X[:,None]**np.arange(3)
Out[8]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 4],
       [1, 3, 9]])
```

If `X` is already extended, just *raise to power* -

```
In [24]: X = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])

In [25]: X**np.arange(3)
Out[25]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 4],
       [1, 3, 9]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a specific function, but you could use array broadcasting.

```
 X = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
 p = np.arange(0, 2+1)  # powers
 X**p  # row vs column vector broadcasts to 2D matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

If `n` is large, I would suggest you use nested loop instead. Calculating power is expensive. Do something like this:

```
arr = [1]
for i in range(1, p + 1):
   arr.append(p * arr[-1])
```